# Addon not running/ui not showing

Tags: python, add-on

When I enable my addon the ui does not show. I tryed adding a print statement to see if that does anything (it does not). Idk if it is my code but here it is

````py
bl_info = {
    "name": "Illumin8r",
    "author": "BinaryOdysseus",
}

import bpy
print("Hi")






def create_point_light1(name):
    collection = bpy.context.collection
    light_data = bpy.data.lights.new(name=name, type='POINT')
    light_data.color = (1,1,1)
    light_data.energy = 100
    light_data.shadow_soft_size = 1.75

    light_object = bpy.data.objects.new(name=name, object_data=light_data)
    light_object.location = (1.35, -2.5, 2.56)
    
    bpy.context.collection.objects.link(light_object)

def create_point_light2(name):
    
    light_data = bpy.data.lights.new(name=name, type='POINT')
    light_data.color = (1,1,1)
    light_data.energy = 250
    light_data.shadow_soft_size = 1.75

    light_object = bpy.data.objects.new(name=name, object_data=light_data)
    light_object.location = (-1.175, -5.5, 4.64)
    
    bpy.context.collection.objects.link(light_object)
    
def create_point_light3(name):
    
    light_data = bpy.data.lights.new(name=name, type='POINT')
    light_data.color = (1,1,1)
    light_data.energy = 500
    light_data.shadow_soft_size = 2.15

    light_object = bpy.data.objects.new(name=name, object_data=light_data)
    light_object.location = (-6.7, -0.1, 2.2)
    
    bpy.context.collection.objects.link(light_object)
    
def create_point_light4(name):
    
    light_data = bpy.data.lights.new(name=name, type='POINT')
    light_data.color = (1, 0.612277, 0.441099)
    light_data.energy = 1000
    light_data.shadow_soft_size = 3.17
    
    light_object = bpy.data.objects.new(name=name, object_data=light_data)
    light_object.location = (0, -0.6, 3.2)
    
    bpy.context.collection.objects.link(light_object)
    
def create_spot_light(name):
    
    light_data = bpy.data.lights.new(name=name, type='SPOT')
    light_data.color = (1, 0.868938, 0.686679)
    light_data.energy = 10000
    light_data.spot_size = 180


    light_object = bpy.data.objects.new(name=name, object_data=light_data)
    light_object.location = (0, 0, 14)
    
    bpy.context.collection.objects.link(light_object)
    

    
def create_sun_light(name):
    target_obj = bpy.context.view_layer.objects[0]
    light_data = bpy.data.lights.new(name=name, type='SUN')
    light_data.color = (1, 0.984, 0.675)

    light_object = bpy.data.objects.new(name=name, object_data=light_data)
    light_constraint = light_object.constraints.new(type='TRACK_TO')
    light_object.location = (0, 0, 14)
    light_constraint.target = target_obj
    light_constraint.track_axis = 'TRACK_NEGATIVE_Z'
    light_constraint.up_axis = 'UP_Y'
    
    bpy.context.collection.objects.link(light_object)



def button1(context):

    create_point_light1("Point")
    create_point_light2("Point")
    create_point_light3("Point")
    create_point_light4("Point")
    create_spot_light("Spot")
    create_sun_light("Sun")


class Add_Lights(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "illumin8r.add_lights"
    bl_label = "Add quick lights"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        button1(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
def button2(context):
    bpy.ops.object.select_by_type(type = 'LIGHT')
    bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False, confirm=False)

class Remove_Lights(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "illumin8r.remove_lights"
    bl_label = "Remove all lights"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        button2(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
def button3(context):

    bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_percentage = 200
    bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.file_format = 'HDR'
    
    camera_data = bpy.data.cameras.new(name="hi")


    camera_object = bpy.data.objects.new(name="HDRI Camera", object_data=camera_data)
    camera_object.location = (0, 0, 4)
    camera_object.rotation_euler = (1.5707963267949, 0,0)
    camera_object.data.type = 'PANO'
    camera_object.data.cycles.panorama_type = 'EQUIRECTANGULAR'


    
    bpy.context.collection.objects.link(camera_object)
    
class Make_Scene_HDRI(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "illumin8r.make_scene_hrdi"
    bl_label = "Turn scene into HDRI"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        button3(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
def button4(context):
    bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_percentage = 100
    bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.file_format = 'PNG'

class Make_Scene_Normal(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "illumin8r.make_scene_normal"
    bl_label = "Turn settings back to normal"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        button4(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}
        
    
    
    
    
    



def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(SimpleOperator.bl_idname, text=SimpleOperator.bl_label)






class LayoutDemoPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the scene context of the properties editor"""
    bl_label = "Illumin8r Quick Lights"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_layout"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        scene = context.scene

       


        # Big buttons
        row = layout.row()
        row.scale_y = 1.25
        row.operator("illumin8r.add_lights")
        
        row = layout.row()
        row.scale_y = 1.25
        row.operator("illumin8r.remove_lights")

class LayoutDemoPanel2(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the scene context of the properties editor"""
    bl_label = "Illumin8r HDRI Maker"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_layout_2"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        scene = context.scene

        # Big buttons
        row = layout.row()
        row.scale_y = 1.25
        row.operator("illumin8r.make_scene_hrdi")

        row = layout.row()
        row.scale_y = 1.25
        row.operator("illumin8r.make_scene_normal")





def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(Make_Scene_HDRI)
    bpy.utils.register_class(Make_Scene_Normal)
    bpy.utils.register_class(Remove_Lights)  
    bpy.utils.register_class(Add_Lights)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.append(menu_func)
    bpy.utils.register_class(LayoutDemoPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(LayoutDemoPanel2)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Make_Scene_HDRI)  
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Make_Scene_Normal)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Remove_Lights)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Add_Lights)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.remove(menu_func)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(LayoutDemoPanel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(LayoutDemoPanel2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a proper `bl_info`

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Illumin8r",
    "author": "BinaryOdysseus",
    'description': '',
    'blender': (3, 3, 0),
    'version': (0, 1, 0),
    'category': 'General',
    'location': '3D View',
    'support': 'COMMUNITY',
    'warning': '',
    'doc_url': '',
    'tracker_url': ''
}
```

It is in the `Scene Properties`

[image]

If you want it to be in `N-Panel`

change

```
bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
bl_context = "scene"
```

to

```
bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
bl_region_type = 'UI'
bl_category = "Addon"
```